# Exclude components code from production environment in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I would like to exclude certain components from my production build in Angular 5+. So far I have read around and I understand the concepts of environment variables, but to my understanding those are available at runtime. What I am looking for is to actually exclude certain modules from ever being imported so that the code for them does not get to the production build (files).

I also dont want to have an 
`<div *ngIf="isProduction">...</div>` laying around, what I would rather want to do is something like this:

`Component({
  ...
  templateUrl: environment.production ? 'app.prod.html' : 'app.html'
})`

However this is also not possible due to how the Angular compiler works.

I guess the answer to this is to tweak the `angular-cli`, but given there is no good documentation (that I can find), I'd like to know if someone perhaps has a better idea?

Comment: Spent a while searching for a good answer and I still can't seem to find one. @Max101 Have you managed to find a solution better than the one I've posted below?

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for a *not so scalable* solution.

*Solution is for **Angular 5 / Angular 6+***

You can switch specific files depending on what environment you are building/serving by adding each file pair in the **angular.json** file.

For example, if you wish to use app.prod.html instead of app.html in your app component only when using the production environment / configuration.

In **angular.json** add your replacments in the fileReplacements array under the config you wish to have replaced:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        ...
        "fileReplacements": [
          ...
          *** ADD YOUR REPLACEMENT FILES HERE ***
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above example:

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        ...
        "fileReplacements": [
          ...
          {
            "replace": "src/app/app.html",
            "with": "src/app/app.prod.html"
          }
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not a pretty solution as it seems you will be doing this for each file you wish to replace but it should work nontheless.

---

*Build or serve the specific config with*

```
ng serve --configuration=production
ng build --configuration=production
```

Comment: Yep I ended up figuring the same thing .. I believe this is the only current supported way of achieving this...